# In ActionBar set four icon in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How can i set four icons(Bookmarks,search,menu,locationdrop) in ActionBar like a image [image]?

Is it possible through action bar or not ? or tell me any other option .

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.comida.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

style.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name ="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>

    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#f26925</item>
        <item name="android:logo">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/CustomTextColor</item>
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> <!-- Hides the Action Bar -->
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item> <!-- Hides the status bar -->
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTextColor" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance" >
        <item name="android:textColor">#0000ff</item>



    </style>

</resources>
```

It is coming like this image using this .

[image]

Comment: You can use tabview or toolbar for this behaviour

Comment: you use like this menu
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
         android:icon="@mipmap/image"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>

Comment: how i would set four icons ?

Comment: @Prag'sシ could you please explore more ?

Comment: toolbar is dynamic than actionbar, plus actionbar is depricated now. you can design toolbar the way you want. Please look for appropriate tutorials for this. Or you can use tab view for creating TABs. It it more useful when you you have different pages and want to open from same place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Toolbar` from `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`. It's support custom layout in it.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-ToolBar